# How do I use google sheets to remove items as they are selected from a list that may include duplicates

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-filter

I would like column C to be column A with everything in column B filtered out. Column A may have duplicates and those should carry over into column C, unless the same number of that item appears in column B, as pictured. Is there a function able to do this, or would I need to use an app script to accomplish this? [image: column C is generated from the column A and B inputs]

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 1):

The formula returns values from a column after first removing blanks and any values matched *one-to-one* in another column.

For example, if there are 5 instances of the cell value **`alpha`** in column A, and 2 instances of **`alpha`** in column B, then 3 unmatched instances will be returned because **`alpha`** instances 3, 4, & 5 from column A are unmatched while instances 1 & 2 are matched in B.

## Formula

```
=LET(rangeA, A:A, rangeB, B:B, 
   _a, SORT(TOCOL(rangeA,1)),
   _b, TOCOL(rangeB,1),
   calc, LAMBDA(x, TOCOL(BYROW(UNIQUE(x), 
     LAMBDA(ux, LET(fx, FILTER(x, x=ux), 
       TOROW(ARRAYFORMULA(fx & 
       SEQUENCE(ROWS(fx))))))),1)),
   FILTER(_a, NOT(COUNTIF(calc(_b), calc(_a)))))
```

## Explanation

1. **`rangeA`** stores the initial column of values.
2. **`rangeB`** stores the column to check for duplicates.
3. **`_a`** is a sorted array from **`rangeA`** with the blanks removed.
4. **`_b`** is an array from **`rangeB`** with the blanks removed.
5. **`calc`** stores a LAMBDA formula that is used to convert any column of values that may include duplicates into a column of unique values.  This formula is stored as a LAMBDA so it can be reused which eliminates unnecessary code duplication.

   1. The values are made unique by appending (joining) a number to each value using the following logic:

      1. All unique values have **`1`** appended to them. eg. If **`alpha`**  and **`charlie`** are unique values,  then **`alpha1`** and **`charlie1`** are returned.
      2. For duplicate values, a sequence of numbers is appended starting from **`1`**. eg. If **`bravo`** appears three times, then  **`bravo1, bravo2, bravo3`** would be returned.
   2. The LAMBDA stores the column it is passed in the variable **`x`**.
   3. The LAMBDA's formula is a BYROW function that uses UNIQUE to remove any duplicates from **`x`** before passing them one-by-one into another LAMBDA function which stores the current value in **`ux`**. For each **`ux`**, that LAMBDA's formula:

      1. FILTERs **`x`** for any values that match **`ux`** and stores the result in **`fx`**.
      2. Creates an array that's a number SEQUENCE from **`1`** to the total number of values in **`fx`**
      3. Appends the number sequence to the array **`fx`** inside an ARRAYFORMULA that is itself inside a TOROW function.
      4. The process is repeated for each **`x`** until none remain.
      5. The resulting array of rows is converted to a column.
   4. So, if **`x`** is

      ```
      {"alpha";"bravo";"bravo";"bravo";"charlie"}
      ```

      Then **`ux`** is

      ```
      {"alpha";"bravo";"charlie"}
      ```

      And calc returns

      ```
      {"alpha1";"bravo1";"bravo2";"bravo3";"charlie1"}
      ```
6. The last step is to FILTER **`_a`** using a COUNTIF on **`calc(_b)`** and **`calc(_a)`**

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different approach:

```
=arrayformula(let(
source,A:A,
remove,B:B,
runcountcat_,lambda(x,
   map(index(x,1):index(x,counta(x)),lambda(each,each&"~"&countif(index(x,1):each,each)))),
regexextract(unique({runcountcat_(source);runcountcat_(remove)},,1),"(.+)~")))
```

Append the running count of entries from both the 'source' and 'remove' lists to each entry using `map`, then use the *exactly once* argument of `unique` on the combined list to leave the remaining entries in the source list, and `regexextract` to eliminate the appended count.

Comment: Thanks nice approach.